# Value from last row of output file and specify into variable

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I have a ETL (pentaho) which give an excel file output from following steps.

Transformation 1:

- Table input (has got SQL statement with `created > DATEVALUE ORDER BY created ASC`)
- Sort rows
- Excel output

Now how can I read last row of the excel output (created column) value and store into text file? So I can make sure when the job re-run then SQL statement `created date` is grater than text file stored value.

Transformation 1:

- Table input (SQL statement like `created > (get the value from text file) ORDER BY created ASC`)
- Sort rows
- Excel output

What would be the simplest way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save last row of the data stream, which matches to last row written to Excel, using a combination of `Group by` and `Text file output` which you can apped right after your `Excel output` step:

- **Group by step:** Set `Last value` in `Type` column of `Aggregates` tab. Take your date field as a `Subject` and give it some `Name` e.g. `last_date`.
- **Text file output step:** Write `last_date` into a file.

You trasformation would then start by a step which reads the `last_date` from file (`Text file input`) and passes it to the `Table input` step where it is used as a parameter of your SQL query.

[image]

Comment: I tried your solution of the first part to get last row written to text file. But struggling to get the 2 part working. Transformation 2: Text file input -- Table input (SQL statement doesn't pull the value from text file if i tick used as a parameter). Can you post an example?

Comment: You need to insert data from `Text file input` step to `Table input` step. This needs to be done in `Table input` step where you select `Text file input` as a value of `Insert data from step` parameter. Than check `Replace variables in script?` and in a SQL code use `?` to insert a value of variable. To check what input field are used as an input of `Table input` use right-click on a step and choose `Show input fields`. I will attach a transformation snapshot..

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `Identify last row in a stream` step. Just keep the rows flowing out of the Excel output step, identify the last row, discard all but that row, then write it to a text file. It would look something like this:

[image]

Comment: This worked well. But how do i get text file input value to Table input on SQL statement. Steps with an example will help. Thanks

Comment: Just make another transform that reads from a `Text file input` step. Then use the value in a `Database Join` step or `Table Input` with a parameter. There are several questions on SO that show examples of doing that. If you still can't get it, comment here or ask another question.